# On Drag event all selected buttons should be coloured in Tkinter Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, events, tkinter

I have a grid of buttons (10X10). I want to generate a mouse drag event on the buttons on which all the selected buttons should be coloured red. I am using Tkinter GUI in Python. If possible the selected buttons should be restricted to the same row where the first button was selected.

```
for x in range(10):
    temp_buttons = []
    for y in range(10):
        b = tk.Button(player1Frame,text=" ",height=2, width=3,padx=8,pady=8)
        b.bind('<Button-3>',  onRightClick)
        b.bind('<Button-1>',onClick)
        b.grid(row=x, column=y)
        temp_buttons.append(b)
        y = y + w
    x=x+w
    y=0
    player1Buttons.append(temp_buttons)

player1Frame.pack(side = LEFT)
```

my code for generating grid.

Comment: Any answer would really help.

Comment: What do you mean by "generate a mouse drag event"?  You want the code to _generate_ an event, or are you asking how to _respond_ to an event? Generating events is highly unusual, especially drag events. Regardless, nowhere in your code do I see you trying to do anything with a drag event.  What have you tried?

Comment: No, user will generate drag events on the button and I have no clue what to write in the onDrag function so I didn't mentioned it in the code. I can get mouse coordinates on click but How will I know on which Button I clicked and started dragging.

Comment: you can use `lambda` in `bind()` or `command=` to assign function with argument(s). But `bind()` executes function with argument `event` which gives you access to clicked button in `event.widget` - ie. `def onRightClick(event): print(event.widget, event.widget['text'])`

Comment: It would help if you created a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To manage dragging you need to bind to the event `<B1-Motion>`. The callback for the event includes an object representing the event. One of the attributes of that object is a reference to the widget that received the event.

An easy way to see that with the code you posted is to add the row and column as an attribute on the widget. You can then print out that row and column in your event handler.

First, assign an attribute to the widget:

```
b.location =  (x,y)
```

Next, create a callback that prints the location:

```
def onDrag(event):
    button = event.widget
    print("dragging row %s column %s" % button.location)
```

Finally, add the binding:

```
b.bind("<B1-Motion>", onDrag)
```

Comment: Though only the first button from which dragging is started is getting coloured instead of all the buttons.

Comment: @kingforever: that is because you are telling only one button to be colored differently. Tkinter can't read your mind.

Comment: Where do I put the code for coloring every button ? Currently I have put it under onDrag function and that's why only that button is colored differently. Should I have to generate a new event for mouse location change or can I handle it differently?

Comment: @kingforever: put the code to color every button wherever you want. Call that code inside `onDrag`. It's as simple as that.